# Powershell Array -ne multiple comparisons

Tags: arrays, powershell-5.0

The following gets the name of the registry Key Name and puts in into an array called $Array

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Clients"  -Name 

$Array
```

I didn't list all the values, but just as an example it returns something like this:

Classes 
Clients
IM Providers 
Intel
Microsoft
Mozilla
mozilla.org
Partner 
Policies

Now what im trying to do is look through the array and if the values are note equal to "Classes", "IM Providers" or "Intel" then delete them from the array.

This is kinda what I was hoping for:

```
    foreach ($letter in $Array)
{
  if($letter.Name -ne "Classes", "IM Providers" "Intel", )
  {

  $Array.Remove($letter)
   
  }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You have one missing comma and one extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using -notin instead of -ne, at least -eq will be non-null if something is contained in the list.  -ne with an array on the left will unfortunately always be non-null.  -not needs parentheses because its precedence is so high.

```
"Classes", "IM Providers", "Intel" -eq "classes"
Classes

"Classes", "IM Providers", "Intel" -eq "classes2"
# $null

-not ("Classes", "IM Providers", "Intel" -eq "classes")
False

-not ("Classes", "IM Providers", "Intel" -eq "classes2")
True
```